# Semi Global Alignment using BioPython

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, pairwise, sequence-alignment

Can we change global alignment using Pairwise2 in BioPython into semi-global alignment using arguments? If so, can you give an example?

Comment: can you explain semi-global? Both `Bio.pairwise2` and `Bio.Align` can perform global or local alignments as documented in the Biopython tutorial